# the out put is to print out the transpose of the matrix from the matrix you type in, but my code just print out the first matrix you type in

Tags: c++

the out put is to print out the transpose of the matrix from the matrix you type in, but my code just print out the first matrix you type in

it doesn't show any error so i don't really know what to do

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int NhapMang(int A[100][100], int n)
{
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
        {
            cout << "Nhap A[" << i << "][" << j << "]: ";
            cin >> A[i][j];
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int XuatMang(int A[100][100], int n)
{
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
        {
            cout << A[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}

int DoiGiaTri(int &a, int &b)
{
    int tam = a;
    a = b;
    b = tam;
    return 0;
}

int ChuyenVi(int A[100][100], int n)
{
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
        {
            DoiGiaTri(A[i][j], A[j][i]);
        }
    }

    XuatMang(A,n);
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int n, A[100][100];
    cout << "moi nhap n: ";
    cin >> n;
    NhapMang(A,n);
    XuatMang(A,n);
    cout << "\nma tran chuyen vi: \n";
    ChuyenVi(A,n);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

you type in n, for example n=3, the matrix:

```
1 2 3 
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

the tranpose of matrix will be :

```
1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

but the actual result the tranpose of matrix

```
1 2 3
4 5 6 
7 8 9
```

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: You might be swapping stuff around twice. And the transpose of the transpose is...

Comment: If that actually is the case, you could have found the error yourself if you had extracted the [mcve] that is actually required. As a new user, make sure you take the [tour] and read [ask], too!

Comment: Using English function and variable names helps people understand your code - most of us don't understand your mother tongue and need to guess from code what it actually does - admitted, not difficult at all in given case, but in more complex scenarios this can get a true issue. Just for comparison: What might functions named like the following do? `liesEin`, `gibAus`, `vertausche`, `transponiere`...

Answer (score 4):

You swap everything twice, so it ends up the same as when you started. Try this, I've commented the line that changes.

```
int ChuyenVi(int A[100][100], int n)
{
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<i; j++) // <-- change here
            {
            DoiGiaTri(A[i][j], A[j][i]);
            }
    }
    XuatMang(A,n);
    return 0;
}
```